# How to get the content text from the selected item ListPicker Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a problem here to take the text from selected item inside of my ListPicker,i found this code who allows me to do that

```
var content = ((ListPickerItem)CursoLista.SelectedItem).Content;
```

and my XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="CursoLista" Header="Curso" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Curso}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

as you can see,the content is Binding to a List from my server:

```
private void Cliente_ProfessorRetrieveCompleted(object sender, Service.ProfessorRetrieveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        CursoLista.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

but when i try to do this,i have an Execption :

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'FaculdadeGuararapes.Service.ListaProfessor' to type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPickerItem'.
```

FaculdadeGuararapes.Service.ListaProfessor its the list who comes from my WebServer!

Comment: `CursoLista.SelectedItem` is a type of your list model `ListaProfessor`. If you just want to retrieve this model from your list, try: 
`var content = CursoLista.SelectedItem as ListaProfessor;`

Comment: @marcinax hi,look its not working,whem i use
`CursoLista.ItemsSource = e.Result;` its come from the server a List with 5 objects "strings" and i just filtring to my ListPicker one value which is Curso,if i use as you say`
`var content = CursoLista.SelectedItem as ListaProfessor;` will take all objects but i just want one Curso!

Comment: So what is bound here:  `<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Curso}"/>` What is the type of `e.Result`? It looks like list of models with property Curso, not strings.

Comment: I put a longer answer below.

Comment: @marcinax yes you right! I'm sorry about it, when i said Strings was the type of property,but i will try to use what you say!

Comment: Show the model used to binding (in which `Curso` property is). What does `e.Result` exactly return? ;). Probably in `SelectedItem' is your model used to binding.

Comment: @marcinax can we start a chat? i think will be better to i explain to you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93083/discussion-between-marcinax-and-nathiel-paulino).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if your `e.Result` is a list of strings and you set `CursoLista.ItemsSource` from code behind, you don't need to add `ItemsSource` in xaml. Next, if you want to retreive single selected item, just pin to `SelectionChanged` event. Additionally, probably it's not necessary to add `<DataTemplate>`. `DataTemplate` is only necessary when you want to customize a layout or bind to the class.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="CursoLista" Header="Curso" SelectionChanged="CursoLista_SelectionChanged">
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and handle it in code behind:

```
    private void CursoLista_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         string selectedString = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as string;
    }
```